# how to add Panel from different class on pressing button

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

i want to add panel from "newWork" class on pressing of "drop" button in "menuPan" class. 
i cant add panel.
simply how to add Panel from different class on pressing button. 
here are the three different classes . 
MainClass :-

```
public class userFrame  extends JFrame{

 public void Frame() 
    {
    setTitle("TEST CASE");
    setSize(900,670);

    add(new MenuPan(),BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(new WorkPan(),BorderLayout.CENTER);


    setLocationRelativeTo(this);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
public static void main(String [] args){
    userFrame u =new userFrame();
    u.Frame();
}
}
```

MenuPan

```
public class MenuPan  extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
WorkPan work=new WorkPan();
JButton view;
public menuPan() {
    setBackground(Color.white);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY));
    setLayout(new FlowLayout(1, 15, 10));
    view=new JButton(" Registered Courses ");
    view.addActionListener(this);
    add(view);
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    work.TaskPannel();
}
}
```

WorkPAN class :-

```
 class WorkPan extends JPanel{
   JPanel work=new JPanel();
   public WorkPan() {
     setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
     setLayout(new BorderLayout(40, 50));

   }

   void TaskPannel() {
      System.out.println("here");
      add(new NewWork(),BorderLayout.CENTER);// adds NewWork panel 
   }
}
```

NewWork Class

```
  class NewWork extends JPanel{

  public NewWork(){

     setBackground(Color.red);       

  }
  }
```

Comment: We can't run or compile your code making it hard for us to answer your question. Consider creating a valid [mcve] -- but please first read the link as well as the [sscce](http://sscce.org) link.

Comment: i just want to add a new panel (NewWork) on the center of frame . Thanks

Comment: Good luck with this. Again if you need further help, you will need to create and post your [mcve]. Up to you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sir i have updated my question with minimal, complete varifiable example as You said. Thanks for your time

Comment: Thanks,  your code proves that you're creating too many workPan objects. The one you display is created anonymously and not even placed into a field -- don't do that. Create a workPan field, fill it with an object, place it in the GUI and use the same object in the listener.

Comment: Welcome @HovercraftFullOfEels  tried this also, but nothing

Comment: Please edit your question -- keep your original code, but also post below the new code where you try this. Let's see what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue -- you create one workPan (which should be renamed WorkPan), change its state in your ActionListener, but never add it to your GUI. So you appear to be changing the state of a non-displayed GUI component, and so it would make sense that nothing will show in the GUI.

Suggestions:

- Be sure to create only **one** WorkPan reference,
- Be sure to display this single reference in the GUI
- Be sure that your ActionListener calls the appropriate method on the **same reference**.

Side recommendation:

- Learn and follow Java naming conventions so you others can more easily understand and follow your code.
- To swap JPanels within a GUI, I strongly advise you to use a CardLayout rather than adding and removing components manually as you're currently doing. Please check out the [CardLayout Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

And my solution **does** work, but you also must call revalidate and repaint to get the GUI to layout the new component and repaint it. Note additions and changes as marked by the `\\ !!` comment

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FooWork {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            userFrame.main(args);
        });
    }
}

class NewWork extends JPanel {
    public NewWork() {
        setBackground(Color.red);
    }
}

class WorkPan extends JPanel {
    JPanel work = new JPanel();

    public WorkPan() {
        setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(40, 50));
    }

    void TaskPannel() {
        System.out.println("here");
        add(new NewWork(), BorderLayout.CENTER);// adds NewWork panel

        // !!
        revalidate();
        repaint();
        // !!
    }
}

class MenuPan extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    // !! WorkPan work = new WorkPan();
    WorkPan work; // !!
    JButton view; // !!

    // !!
    public MenuPan(WorkPan workPan) { // references are key

        // !!
        this.work = workPan; // set the reference!
        // !!

        setBackground(Color.white);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY));
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(1, 15, 10));
        view = new JButton(" Registered Courses ");
        view.addActionListener(this);
        add(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        work.TaskPannel();
    }
}

class userFrame extends JFrame {
    public void Frame() {
        setTitle("TEST CASE");
        setSize(900, 670);

        // !!
        WorkPan workPan = new WorkPan();
        MenuPan menuPan = new MenuPan(workPan);
        // !!

        // !!
        // add(new MenuPan(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        // add(new WorkPan(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(menuPan, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(workPan, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // !!

        setLocationRelativeTo(this);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        userFrame u = new userFrame();
        u.Frame();
    }
}
```

But again, cleaner is to use a CardLayout to help with the swapping:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SwapStuff {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        SwapMainPanel mainPanel = new SwapMainPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SwapStuff");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class SwapMainPanel extends JPanel {
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);
    private ButtonPanel buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel(this); // pass the reference
    private WorkPanel workPanel = new WorkPanel();
    private ViewPanel viewPanel = new ViewPanel();

    public SwapMainPanel() {
        cardPanel.add(workPanel, workPanel.getClass().getName());
        cardPanel.add(viewPanel, viewPanel.getClass().getName());

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(cardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    // one possible way to swap "cards"
    public void nextCard() {
        cardLayout.next(cardPanel);
    }
}

class ButtonPanel extends JPanel {
    private SwapMainPanel mainPanel;

    public ButtonPanel(SwapMainPanel mainPanel) {
        this.mainPanel = mainPanel;  // set the reference!
        add(new JButton(new SwapAction("Swap Panels", KeyEvent.VK_S)));
    }

    private class SwapAction extends AbstractAction {
        public SwapAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            mainPanel.nextCard();
        }
    }
}

class WorkPanel extends JPanel {
    public WorkPanel() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Work Panel"));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 400);
    }
}

class ViewPanel extends JPanel {
    public ViewPanel() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("View Panel"));
        setBackground(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 400);
    }
}
```

Comment: i just want to add a new panel (NewWork) on the center of frame . Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah: see changes to answer. My concerns were correct.

Comment: Thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels 
I really appreciate it :)